# Microsoft Word Restore Previous Version of Unsaved File

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, restore

I was authoring an email on Microsoft Word for 30 minutes. I cut the document with the intention of pasting it into an email and got distracted so I didn't.

My computer then crashed and after restart and opening Word again, I found that the recovered file was the state of the file after I selected everything and performed the cut, that is, now the file has nothing. And there doesn't seem to be a way to do 'undo'.

I know I'm a genius for not saving the file, and for cutting without pasting. Any ideas how to deal with the consequences of such brilliance?

Comment: Restore the document from a backup you have.  That is the only solution to a problem like this.  If a backup does not exist, create one now, so you don't repeat the same mistake.  Your unsaved changes, and document you wanted to recover, was lost when the computer crashed.  Be sure you determine the reason your computer crashed, because that indicates a larger problem, if your computer crashes.  (My computer stays on 24/7 and has never crashed while I using it nor while I wasn't using it)

Comment: Backup could simply mean an extra copy, is that what you mean? Or do you mean some feature that is built into Word? I do have a big electrical issue with my 4 year old laptop, including dents and broken pieces here and there. The computer totally crashes when I apply some pressure to the left of the mouse pad!

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a way. MS Word restores the saved hiding version of document. 
To avoid this issue in the future, don't cut. Copy. And save, whatever you work on, regularly.

Comment: This is more of a comment then an actual answer.  You indicate, "you don't think there is a way", we typically want answers to be more definite then that.  Consider earning yourself more reputation so you can leave comments yours to questions in the future.

Comment: I don't think there is a way. MS Word restores the saved hiding version of document. 
To avoid this issue in the future, don't cut. Copy. And save, whatever you work on, regularly.

Comment: You just made a comment, to your own answer, that duplicate your answer.  You need to earn reputation by answering questions.  You should attempt to only questions, when you know beyond a shadow of a doubt, that the answer you are providing is correct.

Comment: I did realize that I am taking too long to paste, so I corrected that issue by simply undoing the cut in Word and then copying. Then the computer crashed a couple of minutes after that. I think the auto-recover feature captures the state of the document every 10 minutes... I think it would be great if Microsoft Word also recovered the editing history (to allow undo/redo) of the file when it stores it for recovery!